# static initialisation of a char array in a constant struct from C to C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, initialization

I have some existing code in C:

```
extern const struct sockaddr_un addr =
{
    .sun_family = AF_UNIX,
    .sun_path   = "myreallylongpath"
};
```

Where sun_path is a character array.

This used to compile fine as C in an older version of GCC. I have now converted it to C++ and am using GCC v4.7.2. I keep getting the error:

> "C99 designator 'sun_path' outside aggregate intializer"

Is it not possible to do what I am doing in C++, or is the syntax different from the old C?

Comment: If you are converting the whole code to C++, consider adding a constructor to sockaddr_un and using it to create the instance.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That is a structure from standard POSIX C API. You can't add constructor to it (ok, you can add a named constructor, but I don't think it makes much sense).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Designated initializers were introduced in C99, GCC also supports them as an extension in GNU89, but not in C++.

So you need to use the C89 style, which is also supported in C++. Since the struct has only these two fields:

```
extern const struct sockaddr_un addr =
{
    AF_UNIX,
    "myreallylongpath"
};
```

Reference: [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

Comment: So the downside is that if that library struct changes we get the wrong data in the wrong places. Mind you, if they change that definition it'd probably "break the world" anyway. :-P

Comment: @Joe: It's a standard interface from POSIX specification. It didn't change for 40 or so years and can't change without making the sky fall down. In this particular case I definitely wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: `Since the struct has only these two fields` is a false assumption. In my case my struct has well over a dozen fields, of which only four are set. This answer doesn't explain what to do in this situation when converting C code to C++.